# Angular2 ngStyle multiple class binding does not work

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an application that dynamically create some form, using angular2 ans bootstrap 3. I have some trouble when I try to style my components dynamically using the bootstrap grid.

I wrote this:

```
[ngStyle]="['col-xs-12','col-sm-'+field.span,'col-md-'+field.span,'col-lg-'+field.span]"
```

'field' is correctly bounded and I got no error, the 'span' property is a number between 1 and 12, exploring the dom the div seems not to be styled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngStyle` has a different purpose or is used differently. It seems what you want is `ngClass`

```
[ngClass]="['col-xs-12','col-sm-'+field.span,'col-md-'+field.span,'col-lg-'+field.span]"
```

An `ngStyle` use case would be something like

```
[ngStyle]="{color: someColorProperty}"
```